# How to use routes from Express for HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, express, https

I'm enabling https requests toward my nodeJS server. But I would like to use the same routes that I can receive from http requests with that 8080 port to my https with that 443 port.

http://api.myapp.com:8080/api/waitlist/join is successful
https://api.myapp.com:443/api/waitlist/join isn't
What do I miss in the code to use the same routes as for 'app' for httpsServer?

```
var fs              = require('fs');
var https           = require('https');
var express         = require('express');       // call express
var app             = express();                // define our app using express
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var cors            = require('cors');
var config          = require('./config');

// Configure app to use bodyParser()
[...]
// Configure the CORS rights
app.use(cors());

// Enable https 
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

// Configure app port
var port            = process.env.PORT || config.app.port; // 8080

// Configure database connection
[...]

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================

// Create our router
var router = express.Router();

// Middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('>>>> Something is happening. Here is the path: '+req.path);
    next();
});

// WAITLIST ROUTES ---------------------------------------
// (POST) Create Email Account --> Join the waitList
router.route('/waitlist/join').post(waitlistCtrl.joinWaitlist);
// And a lot of routes...


// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// All of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);



// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [API docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) for `.listen` on my own projects with similar need, and looking at your code, I think two quick changes should work:

1) add `var http = require('http');` to the top with your other requires.

2) change the last two lines of the app to:

```
// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
http.createServer(app).listen(port);
https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(443);
```

(If this works, you can also remove the reference to `httpsServer`.)

Answer (score 3):

Truthfully, unless you have a very good reason not to I'd look at putting either a web server (NGINX) in front of your node app or a load balancer.

This helps in a number of ways, not the least of which being that you can terminate the HTTPS request there and let your node app not care.